# AJAX load PHP file

Tags: php, ajax

I am a newbie on AJAX, I have a link that loads table.php. Then it writes the code to the index.php. In that code, I have another link to
show the info.php. Is it possible to do this?

```
<!--This is index.php-->
<div id="link"><a href="info">my Info</a></div><!--it works here-->
<div id="link"><a href= "table">My Table</a></div>
<div id="table"></div>
<div id="info"></div>

<!--My javascript-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#link a').click(function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        if(page =='table')
            $('#table').load('table.php');
        else if(page =='info')
            $('#info').load('info.php');
        return false;
    })
});
</script>


<!--This is table.php-->
<div id="link"><a href="info">my Info</a></div><!--it doesn't works here-->

<!--This is info.php-->
<h1>My info</h1>
```

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Does Firebug / other JS debugger say anything about it?

Comment: Try to change `$(this).attr('href');` to `$(this).prop('href');`

Comment: @PranavKapoor Well how about 3 times from top to down ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your three `<div>` (as pointed out by @scragar) have the same id `link`, most probably causing the issue. Make it a class like that :

```
<div class="link">
```

And in your JS :

```
$('.link a')
```

EDIT : As noted by dbf, you must as well declare your handler with `live()` or `on()` instead of `click()` :

```
$('.link a').live('click', function(){ ... });
```

in order for it to be binded after `table.php` is loaded in the page. ( http://api.jquery.com/live/ )

Comment: He has three divs with that ID, not two.

Comment: @tchap You mean changing it to a class (which is a good suggestion) will magically add a click handler to the given `<a>` element from the `table.php` file when inserting it into the DOM?

Comment: I guess yes, `$(this)` being the culprit here

Comment: @tchap Then you guess wrong, you have to rebind the `click` handler specifically after the content gets loaded into `#table`, else `<a href="info">my Info</a>` from `table.php` will just land into nirvana following the link `info`, which is probably not what he wants. He wants the `<a>` element from `table.php` to load content into `#info` from `info.php` ..